# Test Database Connection is OK before con.Open()

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-ce

I have created a generic Database handler class for my app.

Im using a local database so `SqlCeConnection` class is being used here.

What I would like to do is test that the Connection string is valid, so update the connection status to the user before I execute `connection.Open();`

lets say

```
 SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);

 //so far we have only created the connection, but not tried to open it
 //Would be nice to update the UI to say that conn is OK
 conn.testConnection();

 conn.Open();
```

I was thinking of writing a method that attempts to `open` then `close` the connection, am I right in thinking this or is there a better way.

Comment: Just like with an email address, the only way to *really* know it is valid is to try and use it. In this case that is open a test connection. Opening (and closing) a connection will take very little time. So .. just write it. I would utilize `finally` as well, and abstract it all away in a `TestConnection` method: `if (!TestConnection(..)) { ShowError(..) }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

testing for connectivity adds extra overhead. why not directly open connection and put the code inside `Try-Catch`

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
}
catch(SqlCeException ex)
{
    // output the error to see what's going on
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
}
```

Comment: Its a local database, so the server is localhost, is it still better to try catch ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DbConnectionStringBuilder` with property `ConnectionString`, it will throw exception if [connection string is not correct format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.connectionstring.aspx):

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void TestConnection(this DbConnection connection)
    {
        var builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                ConnectionString = connection.ConnectionString
            };
    }
}
```

With this way you don't need to really open connection to database.

Comment: I like this idea, I tried it but now compiler gives me an error->Error 1 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class C:\.....\WindowsFormsApplication\Classes\DatabaseConnection.cs 11 18

Comment: @IEnumerable: put this code on static class Extension, edit my answer